# property overrideSelector does not exist on type Store<state> ngrx/store@8.2

Tags: ngrx-store, angular8

I am adding a test that needs to return a different mock value for a selector. So I found a nice way of doing it using overrideSelecor as mentioned here  https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing. But when adding **mockstore.overrideSelector**,  got this error "property overrideSelector does not exist on type Store". Has anyone fixed this before?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 the mockStore does not have that function indeed. Migrating to Angular 8 will fix your issue.

Comment: When I had this problem, we were using Angular 7 with NGRX 8.0. However upgrading the entire project to Angular 8 has resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely just typings issue. If you use `provideMockStore` it in fact creates an instance of `MockStore` that is provided as `Store` instance on DI so it won't break you apps functionality.

So in your tests you should use it like this:

```
let store: MockStore<State>;
...
store = TestBed.get<Store<State>>(Store);
...
store.overrideSelector(...);
```